# Oauth2 multiple client node js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I'm programming a server oauth2 with node.js for my society using the github example https://github.com/pedroetb/node-oauth2-server-example

It's actually work, but i just have a difficult to know how to use multiple client ? 
In other words, the variable config in model.js actually have data for only one client and I want to use several client.

thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english.